# How to add event callbacks to sqlalchemy models?

Tags: events, callback, sqlalchemy

There is a page demonstrates how to do it when using Elixir:

http://beachcoder.wordpress.com/2007/05/02/adding-event-callbacks-to-sqlalchemyelixir-classes/

But I don't use Elixir, I just use `sqlalchemy` directly, and define my models as:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    ...

    def send_email(self):
        # send email to the user
```

And what I want to do is:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    ...
    before_insert('init_user', 'send_email')
    before_delete('something_before_delete')

    def init_user(self):
        # init some data of the user
    def send_email(self):
        # send email to the user
    def something_before_delete(self):
        # something before delete
```

Note the `before_insert` and `before_delete` methods. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is to use an extension (MapperExtension, SessionExtension...) as described [here](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/orm/interfaces.html).

But you almost certainly don't want to do anything like sending an email in such a hook.  The right way would be to log the action and post-process the log entry after the transaction has completed.

[EDIT] The sqlalchemy docs have changed; the new way of handling this is to use [ORM Events](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/events.html)

Comment: thank for your advice of 'not send email here', it's very important. And, now, I made some callbacks as the page you gave me, but there is another problem. Can you help me to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646486