# Some problems with MapperExtension of sqlalchemy

Tags: insert, sqlalchemy

There are two classes: User and Question

A user may have many questions, and it also contains a question_count 
to record the the count of questions belong to him.

So, when I add a new question, I want update the question_count of the 
user. At first, I do as:

```
question = Question(title='aaa', content='bbb') 
Session.add(question) 
Session.flush() 


user = question.user 
### user is not None 
user.question_count += 1 
Session.commit()
```

Everything goes well.

But I wan't to use event callback to do the same thing. As following:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces import MapperExtension 
class Callback(MapperExtension): 
    def after_insert(self, mapper, connection, instance): 
         user = instance.user 
         ### user is None !!! 
         user.question_count += 1 


class Question(Base): 
    __tablename__ = "questions" 
    __mapper_args__ = {'extension':Callback()} 
    ....
```

1. Note in the "after_insert" method:

   `instance.user # -> Get None!!!`

   Why?
2. If I change that line to:

   `Session.query(User).filter_by(id=instance.user_id).one()`

   I can get the user successfully, But: the user can't be updated!

   Look I have modified the user:

   `user.question_count += 1`

   But there is no 'update' sql printed in the console, and the 
   `question_count` are not updated.
3. I try to add `Session.flush()` or `Session.commit()` in the 
   `after_insert()` method, but both cause errors.

Is there any important thing I'm missing? Please help me, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The author of sqlalchemy gave me an useful answer in a forum, I copy it here:

> Additionally, a key concept of the
>   unit of work pattern is that it
>   organizes a full list of all
>   INSERT,UPDATE, and DELETE statements
>   which will be emitted, as well as the
>   order in which they are emitted,
>   before anything happens.   When the
>   before_insert() and after_insert()
>   event hooks are called, this structure
>   has been determined, and cannot be
>   changed in any way.   The
>   documentation for before_insert() and
>   before_update() mentions  that the
>   flush plan cannot be affected at this
>   point - only individual attributes on
>   the object at hand, and those which
>   have not been inserted or updated yet,
>   can be affected here.   Any scheme
>   which would like to change the flush
>   plan must use
>   SessionExtension.before_flush. 
>   However, there are several ways of
>   accomplishing what you want here
>   without modifiying the flush plan.
>
> The simplest is what I already
>   suggested.   Use
>   MapperExtension.before_insert() on the
>   "User" class, and set
>   user.question_count =
>   len(user.questions).   This assumes
>   that you are mutating the
>   user.questions collection, rather than
>   working with Question.user to
>   establish the relationship.   If you
>   happened to be using a "dynamic"
>   relationship (which is not the case
>   here), you'd pull the history for
>   user.questions and count up what's
>   been appended and removed.
>
> The next way, is to do pretty much
>   what you think you want here, that is
>   implement after_insert on Question,
>   but emit the UPDATE statement
>   yourself.  That's why "connection" is
>   one of the arguments to the mapper
>   extension methods:
>
> ```
> def after_insert(self, mapper, connection, instance): 
>     connection.execute(users_table.update().\ 
>        values(question_count=users_table.c.question_count +1).\ 
>              where(users_table.c.id==instance.user_id))
> ```
>
> I wouldn't prefer that approach since
>   it's quite wasteful for many new
>   Questions being added to a single
>   User.   So yet another option, if
>   User.questions cannot be relied upon
>   and you'd like to avoid many ad-hoc
>   UPDATE statements, is to actually
>   affect the flush plan by using
>   SessionExtension.before_flush:
>
> class
>   MySessionExtension(SessionExtension): 
>       def before_flush(self, session, flush_context): 
>           for obj in session.new: 
>               if isinstance(obj, Question): 
>                   obj.user.question_count +=1
>
> ```
>    for obj in session.deleted: 
>        if isinstance(obj, Question): 
>            obj.user.question_count -= 1
> ```
>
> To combine the "aggregate" approach of
>   the "before_flush" method with the
>   "emit the SQL yourself" approach of
>   the after_insert() method, you can
>   also use SessionExtension.after_flush,
>   to count everything up and emit a
>   single mass UPDATE statement with many
>   parameters.   We're likely well in the
>   realm of overkill for this particular
>   situation, but I presented an example
>   of such a scheme at Pycon last year,
>   which you can see at 
>   http://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/pycon2010/src/tip/chap5/sessionextension.py
>   .

And, as I tried, I found we should update the `user.question_count` in `after_flush`

Answer (score 2):

`user`, being I assume a RelationshipProperty, is only populated after the flush (as it is only this point the ORM knows how to relate the two rows).

It looks like `question_count` is actually a derived property, being the number of Question rows for that user.  If performance is not a concern, you could use a read-only property and let the mapper do the work:

```
@property
def question_count(self):
    return len(self.questions)
```

Otherwise you're looking at implementing a trigger, either at the database-level or in python (which modifies the flush plan so is more complicated).

Comment: thanks. So it is a complicated task? But the requirement is common, if there is a good solution it will be great